# Best way to save millions of records (received from 3rd party API) in SQL DB?

Tags: sql, design-patterns, redis

I'm trying to get medicine names from **[DailyMed API](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/webservices-help/v2/drugnames_api.cfm).** But the API only supports max `100` results **per request** and currently the total elements count **exceeds 97k records.**

I'm not looking for code but just a design that would help me construct an API to serve the purpose: I need to get all the records from DailyMed API daily (Az timer trigger) and update them to my SqlDb/Redis cache *(not implemented yet)*.
I planned to keep the **Get** call in parallel `for` loop and append the data in either a **ConcurrentBag** or **dictionary** (based on diagnostic results I'll choose 1) and then later I've to update the SQL table & Redis cache with the latest record - for that I was planning to store latest records in a temp DB table and then write a SP that validates whether the record exists(Add or Update operation - no delete ops) or to override the original table itself with the Bulk-update with new data **but** with this approach I feel I'm over-engineering things. Also if I override the existing table, this introduces new complexities like what if the table is being read at that same time and most importantly, I don't want to lose the old data; if some medicine is not there next day, I just want to archive (set **isActive** to `false`) it.

Kindly let me know a better approach/design for this problem statement.

*PS:

I'm using Redis as Redis can hold a million records easily and has an expiration time which is helpful in my use case. I'm using SQL as a fallback mechanism*

Comment: Look at publisher/subscriber pattern. Use modern `Channel<T>` in C#.

Comment: How about adding an update date attribute？

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are many possible solutions, I would start by

- Creating two databases

  - `dailymed_main`
  - `dailymed_temp`
- Creating a cron job in which:

  1. `populate()`

     - collect data from DailyMedApi and write data directly to the temp database
  2. `delta()`

     - after completion compare the temp database with the main database and take the required actions

       - if new, insert
       - if removed, update isActive column
       - if row exists but data is different, update
  3. `synch()`

     - after that synchronize the main database with `Redis`
  4. `delete()`

     - delete temp database